# Compute the volume of the solid bounded by $x=0, x=\frac{\pi}{2}, z=0,z=y, y=\cos(x).$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute the volume of the solid bounded by $x=0, x=\frac{\pi}{2}, z=0,z=y, y=\cos(x).$

I'm not sure if I'm mistaken here, but isn't this just $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{y}\int_{0}^{\cos(x)} \ dy \ dz \ dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{y} \cos(x) \ dz \ dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}y\cos(x) \ dx = y$$

this doesn't seem right to me. Is there a problem regarding the limits of $y$?

The picture of the $xy$-plane looks like a $\cos(x)$ bounded between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Well, you can't integrate over $y$ leaving the $y$ as a free variable somewhere (in the limits for instance). First, you have to integrate over $z$ and then over $y$ (and finally over $x$).

Answer (score 1):

Since $z$ depends on $y$ and $y$ depends on $x$, you should integrate first on $z$, so the integral should be
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\cos(x)}\int_{0}^ydz\,dy\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\cos(x)}y\,dy\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(x)^2}{2}dx=\pi/8.$$